# Cocos2d App Crashing After Launch Image on iPhone 5?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, iphone-5

I've searched and there's little to no information on this. My friend has an iPhone 5 and I sent him the build of my application and it installed fine. He goes to open the app and it's crashing after the launch screen. I have no way of gettting a crash report from him right now, so I was wondering if anyone had any idea for quick fixes or reasons why it would crash on an iPhone 5 and run perfectly fine on my iPhone 4s running the same version of iOS as his iPhone 5?

I have the most recent version of cocos2d for iOS, I can post my my app delegate / intro layer if you'd like. But for the most part it's the default stuff.

Any ideas or obvious things to change?

I'll just post my app delegate:

```
// Create the main window
    window_ = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    // Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
    CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

    director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    // Display FSP and SPF
    [director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

    // set FPS at 60
    [director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director_ setView:glView];

    // for rotation and other messages
    [director_ setDelegate:self];

    // 2D projection
    [director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
//  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];

    // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:NO];

    // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
    // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
    // You can change anytime.
    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    // If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
    // On iPad HD  : "-ipadhd", "-ipad",  "-hd"
    // On iPad     : "-ipad", "-hd"
    // On iPhone HD: "-hd"
    CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
    [sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
    [sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
    [sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

    // Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
    [CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];

    // and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
    [director_ pushScene: [IntroLayer scene]]; 


    // Create a Navigation Controller with the Director
    navController_ = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:director_];
    navController_.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    // set the Navigation Controller as the root view controller
//  [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];   // Generates flicker.
    [window_ setRootViewController:navController_];

    // make main window visible
    [window_ makeKeyAndVisible];

    // load game center
    [GameCenterManager loadState];
    [[GameCenterManager sharedGameCenterManager] authenticateLocalPlayer];
```

Comment: It's more likely a problem with the certificates... I'd use something like testflight to get the crash reports online.

Comment: get the crash reports - no point in poking holes in the sky, it won't help get you anywhere near a fix

Comment: I narrowed it down and it happened to be this line in my game center class: [localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {

Comment: I'm getting a SIGABRT error with this being returned in the console: 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES'

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, my GameCenter local player authentication required portrait orientation to be enabled, and landscape was the only thing enabled.